# chrome://inspect UI is broken while inspecting Android emulator

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-inspector

[image]

Several days ago it was working well, however now i get this. Nothing is displayed. UI looks strange

Answer (score 0):

Do these 3 things, and if they don't work, comment on this answer.

> -Restart Chrome 
> -Restart your computer 
> -Uninstall Chrome and reinstall it

Sry for off-topic, but I recommend Firefox DEV (but it's only my opinion)

Comment: Try opening that pannel by pressing CTRL + Shift + I
If it doesn't work, idk... Sorry

Comment: CTRL + Shift + I is different panel. I want to inspect my Android device, not a browser

Comment: Ok, Then I don't really know what to say... Sorry